# Spark View Engine very slow code editing in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, spark-view-engine

How to increase editor responsiveness when typing code for Spark View Engine?
Spark plugin for VS08 takes lot of CPU resources as it checks the syntax of all Spark files on each key stroke: does anyone have an idea how to optimize this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I haven't found a workaround; I also noticed that it tends to eat memory and slow down VS after a while. So I open .spark files as HTML code - this gives good syntax highlighting and tags completion for HTML; I can live without Spark intellisense.